# Show that a homomorphism from $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to $ SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ is surjective

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, field-theory

The homomorphism sends the entries of matrices in  $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ to their congruence classes mod $p$. After a lot of work I could prove that a matrix $$\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\\ c & d\end{pmatrix}$$ in $ SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ has a preimage in $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ if  $a$ and $c$ are relatively prime and I can compute it. But I can't prove the general case and the method I used to prove the preceding assertion was so complicated that it can't be the right way to approach the problem. So there has to be another, more elegant, approach. I attacked the problem head on and ended up with a system of diophantine equations which was difficult to solve as one of the equations was quadratic.

Comment: Prove that $SL_2(\Bbb F_p)$ is generated by $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}$ and $\pmatrix{1&0\\1&1}$.

Comment: Give some details please.

Comment: I am not sure if you had tried the approach any further, but it can be done by Diophantine equations. I think you are on the right track, just push toward it more.

Comment: May be the idea in Lord Shark's comment and Parthiv Basu's (now deleted) answer can be used? See the latter part of [my recent answer to another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3293439/11619) for a description of the textbook method of getting the other elementary row operations in terms of those of this type (subject to the constraint that we are stuck with $\det=1$ matrices). I didn't check all the details, but using the modular inverse of $d$ in place of $d^{-1}$ gives the desired result.

Comment: You're right. I just realized I can reduce an arbitrary matrix in $SL_2(\mathbb{F}_p)$ to the form in your answer using only the row operations that were in Parthiv Basu's answer. And since your form can be written as another product of these row operations, we're done.

Comment: The answer to thisi question can be found in this paper :  https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/grouptheory/SL(2,Z).pdf as Theorem 3.2